# Failing to start debugging services with RustDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rust

I have followed the instructions in the [RustDT user guide](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#user-guide), but when starting to debug, Eclipse stays stuck at "Initializing debugger services".

Am I missing something?

I'm using Windows 7, Eclipse 4.5, Rust 1.1 and GDB 7.9.1.

Comment: What system are you using? What eclipse, Rust and GDB version are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. Eclipse 4.5, Rust 1.1. GDB that comes with MinGW-w64 (not sure how to know which version of GDB it is.

Comment: Just type `gdb` (assuming you have it on the PATH), it will print out version information. Does the Eclipse error log show something? Can you try to debug your rust program using gdb manually?

Comment: GDB version is 7.9.1. I'm not familiar with GDB. How can I use it to debug the rust program manually?

Comment: @Jouan: On SO, comments are meant to be deleted, on top of not being easily parsed (by eye); please edit the relevant details in the question itself, you'll do future readers (and potential answerers) a favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt' anything wrong, there is a problem with RustDT 0.2.1 and the version of CDT that comes with Eclipse 4.5 (CDT 8.7). Use CDT 8.6 (Eclipse 4.4) and it should work fine. ([Issue #44](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/issues/44))

The next RustDT release will have this fixed.

Comment: It should be fixed on this release: https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/releases/tag/v0.2.2